# How to convert XML with multiple prefixes to object

Tags: php, xml, object, soap

We have xml similiar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animal:race>
    <animal:dog>
        <specification:color>Black</specification>
    </animal:dog>
    <animal:cat>
        <animal:name>Flappie</animal:name>
    </animal:cat>
</animal:race>
```

We tried `simplexml_load_file("file.xml",null,null,"animal");`

which returns

```
object(animal:race)#1 (2) { 
    ["dog"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) { 
    }
    ["cat"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { 
        [animal:name] => string "flappie"
    }
}
```

We've seen multiple posts about this but can't seem to get any of this working stripping the prefixes away is not an option cause we need those in a later stage...

Can someone perhaps make a bit of code which converts this to an valid object so that we can adjust it to our own xml.

Comment: Usually the prefix is the XML namespace.  Are you not able to use PHP's built-in SOAP client?  It will parse the XML for you automatically and spit out an object.  You will need a wsdl file to use it.